Elegant way to include standalone.tex graphic in main.tex with consistent font size and full-width frame
What is the most elegant way to include a standalone.tex graphic in my main.tex file such that:

The font size inside the graphic matches the main body text.
The frame around the graphic is the full width of the text body.

Here is my current setup:
standalone.tex:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
             \draw (0,1) -- (1,1.1) node[midway, below] {$x=2$};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}

main.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
        My variable is $x=2$ and on the graphics below

        \fbox
        {
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{standalone}
        }
                
        \fbox
        {
            \includegraphics{standalone}
        }

\end{document}

Output:

Desired Output:


Draw a thicker and longer line and do not use width  to resize the graphic. Alternatively, you can explore the PDF output of Inkscape that allow omit the text may and save it in a  LaTeX file, but again, if you do not have into account the original  and final sizes of the graph, compare the Inkscape draw with the final LaTeX output could be like compare the  day with the night.

if you no not want scale the line either, but only the spaces around as showed in the screenshot,  then you can use \begin{minipage}[c][4cm][c]{17cm} \centering <your picture> \end{minipage}, but  it is up to you ensure that the non-relative width of 17cm (or whatever that you set) will match with  the \textwidth in the final document.

You can try this, but unless you take care of baselines and other typographic dimensions, which the graphic must obey to, too, you'll still have problems:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[6]
        My variable is $x=2$ and here: \fbox{\tikz{\draw (0,1) -- (1,1.1) node[midway, below] {$x=2$};}} \lipsum[5]

\end{document}


The best way to ensure consistency for fonts etc. is not to compile the picture separately, but as part of the main document. If you load the package standalone in your main document, you can \input{} or \includestandalone{} the image source without needing to alter it i.e. you retain the ability to compile it standalone.
To place the resulting image in a frame spanning the width of the text block, you have several options. You could just manipulate the tikz source to alter the bounding box appropriately.

Note that I'm not sure (x,y) -- (x,y,z) is really what you mean here. Are you sure it shouldn't be e.g. (0,1,0) -- (1,1,1) or (0,1) -- (1,1)?
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,1) -- (1,1,1) node  [midway,below] (n) {$x=2$};
  \path (n.center) -- ++(.5\textwidth-0.4pt,0pt) coordinate (b) -- ++(-\textwidth+0.8pt,0pt) coordinate (a);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (current bounding box.north -| a) ++(0pt,2\baselineskip) coordinate (c) -| ([yshift=-2\baselineskip]current bounding box.south -| b) coordinate (d) -| cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

Or use the backgrounds library which provides options for framing. (That seems overkill here, but useful if you want, say, a shaded background.)
You could use a minipage.

\noindent
\fbox
{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}
    \centering
    \input{\jobname-1}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

You could use a tcolorbox. That would be massive overkill here, but would be useful if you wanted something fancier. You could use .
Or you could use a coffin. If you set the image in a vertical coffin of width \textwidth - <adjustments> with \centering, then you can frame the result.

\NewCoffin\MyCoffin

\SetVerticalCoffin \MyCoffin {\dimexpr \textwidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}
{%
  \centering
  \input{\jobname-1}%
}%
\noindent
\fbox
{%
  \TypesetCoffin \MyCoffin [vc,l]%
}

Complete code:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-1.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,1) -- (1,1.1) node[midway, below] {$x=2$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin\MyCoffin
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

My variable is $x=2$ and on the graphics below

\noindent
\fbox
{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}
    \centering
    \input{\jobname-1}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\SetVerticalCoffin \MyCoffin {\dimexpr \textwidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}
{%
  \centering
  \input{\jobname-1}%
}%
\noindent
\fbox
{%
  \TypesetCoffin \MyCoffin [vc,l]%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,1) -- (1,1,1) node  [midway,below] (n) {$x=2$};
  \path (n.center) -- ++(.5\textwidth-0.4pt,0pt) coordinate (b) -- ++(-\textwidth+0.8pt,0pt) coordinate (a);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (current bounding box.north -| a) ++(0pt,2\baselineskip) coordinate (c) -| ([yshift=-2\baselineskip]current bounding box.south -| b) coordinate (d) -| cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

